# New AngularJS Module for Popup window?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

In my application I have a popup window which I need to take data from my initial window.  I understand there are few ways of doing this, session/localStorage or window.open object etc.  My question is since angularjs is SPA oriented, should I use the same module for my popup controller or create an entirely new one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A module is a container for differing pieces of your application, and should be independent of each other.

Read up on it here:  https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module

Regardless of being a [SPA architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application), modules place like source together.  Think of them as a means for encapsulating (and even modularizing) your code into meaningful, self-contained and stand-alone logic.  They should not be dependent on other pieces of your code in different modules, but should be easy to interact with them.

Here is another source for reading: http://henriquat.re/modularizing-angularjs/modularizing-angular-applications/modularizing-angular-applications.html

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the information, although there is no definitive answer... I'm assuming it is a "yes, probably".  I didn't realise one module could depend on another, thanks for the links.  Also nice profile pic, <3 AFX :D

Comment: Yeah, the answer cannot be a solid yes or no.  It is too circumstantial...  Although, I would argue "yes, probably" based on the limited details provided.  Thanks!